# set variable for selected workbook through filepath

Tags: excel, vba

i want to select a workbook from a folder and apply my code to it, however i am unsure of how to set a variable for it.

i have this code that selects the workbook from the folder

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim fileNameAndPath As Variant
fileNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS), *.XLS", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If fileNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileNameAndPath

End Sub
```

how do i set a variable like

```
 Set wscopy = Workbooks("testing.xls").Worksheets("Report")
```

but with the testing.xls being the workbook chosen

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following sub to open file and do some action...

```
Sub OpenWB()
Dim fileNameAndPath As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    fileNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
    If fileNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

    'Set your file to open for operation.
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNameAndPath)
        Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Report")

    ' Do action with open workbook and worksheet.
        MsgBox sht.Range("A1")

    'Close workbook after action is finished.
    wb.Close

    'Clear memory
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set sht = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: it helped, Thank you !

Comment: @mkj2000 If you found the answer helpful then please mark it as accepted (Mark tick as green) so that other user can know the post is solved.